# How to split object strings to array of object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# object:

```
var obj = new Item { xcoords="1,2,3", ycoords="5,6,7", zcoords="8,9,4" }
```

So I want to split this into an array like following:

```
[
   new Item2 { x=1, y=5, z=8 },
   new Item2 { x=2, y=6, z=9 },
   new Item2 { x=3, y=7, z=4 }
]
```

Can I do this using Linq? or another way in c#?

Comment: That looks remarkably JSON-like, save for the property names being unquoted. Do you actually *want* JSON?

Comment: not json, it shout be c# object, the object array is after split operation.

Comment: @barteloma What happens if you get an uneven number of x,y,z? For example, `xcoords` has 3, `ycoords` has 2, and `zcoords` has 4? Also, is `Item2` a `class` or `struct` you have declared?

Comment: What c# version are you on?

Comment: is xcoords actually string, or just laziness and you are dealing with int arrays?

Comment: `item.xcoords.Split(",").Select(int.Parse).Zip(item.ycoords.Split(",").Select(int.Parse), item.zcoords.Split(",").Select(int.Parse)).Select(t => new { x = t.First, y = t.Second, z = t.Third }).ToArray()`. Prettifying this is left as an exercise for the reader, main thing is `Enumerable.Zip` doing the heavy lifting.

Comment: @RyanWilson, all coors contains 3 number of item, not others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a helper method (either as separate method or as local function):

```cs
static IEnumerable<int> ToInts(string s) => s.Split(',').Select(p => Int32.Parse(p));
```

Putting things together:

```cs
var obj = new Item { xcoords = "1,2,3", ycoords = "5,6,7", zcoords = "8,9,4" };

var result = ToInts(obj.xcoords)
    .Zip(ToInts(obj.ycoords), ToInts(obj.zcoords))
    .Select(t => new Item2{ x = t.First, y = t.Second, z = t.Third });
```

Note: this overload of [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2)))) *(since .NET 6?, the doc is wrong on this point)* produces tuples with 3 elements named `First`, `Second` and `Third`.

You can append a `.ToArray()` if you need an array of `Coord`.

---

Test assuming that `ToString` is overridden like this in `Item2`:

```cs
public override string ToString() => $"[{x}, {y}, {z}]";
```

```cs
foreach (var item in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

yields:

```
[1, 5, 8]
[2, 6, 9]
[3, 7, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq approach https://dotnetfiddle.net/CHizmw

```
Item obj = new Item { xcoords = "1,2,3", ycoords = "5,6,7", zcoords = "8,9,4" };
Func<string, int[]> GetInt = value => value.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var helper = new {  xc = GetInt(obj.xcoords), yc = GetInt(obj.ycoords), zc = GetInt(obj.zcoords) };
Item2[] obj2 = Enumerable.Range(0, helper.xc.Length).Select(o =>  new Item2() { x = helper.xc[o], y = helper.yc[o], z = helper.zc[o] }).ToArray();
```

Comment: In this solution `string.Split` method will be called more than it is required. Method result should be cashed to improve performance.

Comment: @DaniilPalii Updated - only 1 split per string

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ here if `coords` number is static.

```cs
var obj = new Item { xcoords="1,2,3", ycoords="5,6,7", zcoords="8,9,4" };

var xcoords = obj.xcoords.Split(',');
var ycoords = obj.ycoords.Split(',');
var zcoords = obj.zcoords.Split(',');

var result = new Item2[]
{
    new Item2 { x = int.Parse(xcoords[0]), y = int.Parse(ycoords[0]), z = int.Parse(zcoords[0]) },
    new Item2 { x = int.Parse(xcoords[1]), y = int.Parse(ycoords[1]), z = int.Parse(zcoords[1]) },
    new Item2 { x = int.Parse(xcoords[2]), y = int.Parse(ycoords[2]), z = int.Parse(zcoords[2]) },
};
```

If `coords` number is dynamic but same for x, y and z then simple "for" loop may resolve the problem.

```cs
var obj = new Item { xcoords="1,2,3,4", ycoords="5,6,7,8", zcoords="8,9,4,10" };

var xcoords = obj.xcoords.Split(',');
var ycoords = obj.ycoords.Split(',');
var zcoords = obj.zcoords.Split(',');

var result = new Item2[xcoords.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < xcoords.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = new Item2
    { 
        x = int.Parse(xcoords[i]),
        y = int.Parse(ycoords[i]),
        z = int.Parse(zcoords[i])
    };
}
```

LINQ version (Requires .NET 6 or higher. In the previous versions `Zip` method takes only 2 collections at once.):

```cs
var obj = new Item { xcoords = "1,2,3,4", ycoords = "5,6,7,8", zcoords = "8,9,4,10" };

var result = Enumerable
    .Zip(
        obj.xcoords.Split(','),
        obj.ycoords.Split(','),
        obj.zcoords.Split(','),
        (x, y, z) => (x, y, z))
    .Select(
        coord => new Item2
        {
            x = int.Parse(coord.x),
            y = int.Parse(coord.y),
            z = int.Parse(coord.z)
        });
```